# Docker build/push every time - is it practical for continuous deployment?

Tags: deployment, continuous-integration, docker, continuous-deployment, dockerhub

Is it really practical to completely rebuild and push a docker image every time you deploy, if you are deploying 5-10 times a day?

I acknowledge the benefits, as mentioned in CircleCI's [Continuous Integration and Delivery with Docker](https://circleci.com/docs/docker), namely:

> Note that Elastic Beanstalk also allows you to deploy a Dockerfile and associated source code instead of a built image, but pre-building the image on CircleCI and running some form of verification on it allows your deployments to be more deterministic because you remove the build environment as a variable that differs between test and production.

However, our fully built webapp image is close to 1GB once all dependencies and source code are included. I just don't see how it's practical to be deploying up to 200GB/month (i.e. 10 commits daily, continuously deployed) when practically 99% of it does not change between builds. i.e. it might just be 1k worth of HTML, JS or CSS that's changed to add a feature. I would prefer an approach where the docker image contains rarely-changed software and the rest is zipped up as part of a bundle. This would still result in a self-contained deploy file (no further dependencies requiring download) but reduce build time and bandwidth substantially.

Comment: So then make a parent dockerfile with the static(ish) stuff, and a final file deriving from that.   Major-Minor versioning.

Comment: or of course you could do it exactly the way you described.  It's all up to you.  Or use git with triggered pulls/staticy image.  Or..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The currently accepted approach is to include a basic Docker image that has the dependencies, the operating system, etc within the machine image. Use that Docker image as the `FROM` line in your Dockerfile. This will take advantage of Docker's image layers and download only the differences.

You may want to still install the dependencies in the child Dockerfile since they will change over time, but try to keep most of them in the base image so there's less to download.

Comment: In an environment like node.js, how do you define 'dependencies'? i.e. up to node.js version (0.10.32, etc) or include `node_modules`? I'm still on the fence whether to include `node_modules` as part of the built image or not. They are far more likely to change than the rest.

Comment: I do include node_modules in the image. In fact I'm convinced by [this somewhat pretentious blog post](http://www.futurealoof.com/posts/nodemodules-in-git.html) that node_modules should be checked in to the repo. If you do that, you don't need an npm install in the Dockerfile. Your build context will be larger but no install required at build time.

Comment: I agree that running `npm install` on production is a bad idea, but I'm still not sure yet on committing node_modules to the repo. If I have our CI server test and then bundle node modules then at least I can be sure that production is same as test, and that my bundle is fully self contained and doesn't require further external downloads once it reaches the production server. Plus if you archive the bundles then you can roll back any time without worrying about npm availability either.